# Expression expected exception with Unity Framework

Tags: vb.net, dependency-injection, unity-container

I am attempting to use Unity Framework for dependency injection. When mapping from the interface to the concrete class Unity displays the "BC30201: Expression expected" message in the MappedTo property of the container. I have spent hours searching Google/Stack Exchange for an answer.

Here is the code :

```
  Dim container As UnityContainer = New UnityContainer
  container.RegisterType(Of DataAccessBase.IMailMerge, AdoDataAccess.MailMergeDataAccess)("connectionString", New Injection.InjectionConstructor(connectionString))
  GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = New UnityApiDependencyResolver(container)
```

Here's a screenshot :
[image: Code and message]